# Linq - find element in nested collections

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I have a generic list - SupportedTypeGroups.

Each SupportedTypeGroup has SupportedTypes property (generic list of SupportedType).

How to construct a Linq query to locate SupportedType with required name?

Answer (score 10):

```
var result = SupportedTypeGroups
             .SelectMany(g => g.SupportedTypes)
             .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "TypeName");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SupportedTypeGroups
  .SelectMany(s => s.SupportedTypes)
  .Where(s => s.name == "TheName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SupportedTypes` is an `IEnumerable<SupportedType>`

```
from g in SupportedTypeGroups
where g.SupportedTypes.Where(t => t.Name == "magicName")
select g;
```

Assuming `SupportedTypes` is just a `SupportedType` property

```
from g in SupportedTypeGroups
where g.SupportedTypes.Name == "magicName"
select g;
```

Asasuming you just want the SupportedType

```
from tg in SupportedTypeGroups
from t in tg.SupportedTypes
where t.Name == "magicName"
select t;
```